# How to drop to a shell during a Capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, deployment, capistrano

Occasionally, an error will occur during a Capistrano deployment that doesn't provide enough output to troubleshoot.  For example:

```
  * executing "cd /apps/my_app/releases/20121019181838 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=dev RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["myserver.com"]
    [myserver.com] executing command
*** [err :: myserver.com] rake aborted!
*** [err :: myserver.com] Connection refused - connect(2)
*** [err :: myserver.com] 
*** [err :: myserver.com] Tasks: TOP => environment
*** [err :: myserver.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 2388ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /apps/my_app/releases/20121019181838; true"
```

Something went wrong during the rake task, and it looks like it probably has something to do with the DB.  But in order to troubleshoot this, I would need to recreate the conditions of the deploy; alas, the conditions have been `rm -rf`'ed.

Is there some way to make Capistrano drop to a (Cap or bash) shell here using a `before` or `after` hook?  Is there an easy way to insert a `--trace` onto that rake task without overriding Capistrano classes?  Other ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I handle situations as such in the following ways:

- When I can be fast enough I simply hit `CTR+Z` (it 'pauses' the cap process) and then I investigate things onsite (over `ssh`, or the `cap console`).
- I set the debug (`cap --debug`) flag when running the task - which makes cap prompt me before each remote command execution, so I can investigate the situation before/after every step.

Both ways usually are sufficient for me to handle the most situations quite quickly.  Hope they will also help you.

Comment: There has got to be a better way to do this.